# How to test if a context.call_activity is done within an orchestration and/or how to limit them?

Tags: python, azure-functions

Let's say I have an orchestrator function which calls 3 tasks.  `task1` has to be complete before it can do `task2` and `task2` has to be complete before `task3`.  However, `task3` doesn't need to finish before it can do the next `task1`.  That being said, I also don't want more than one (maybe 2-3) instances of `task3` running because it's doing db operations so I don't think parallelizing it will make it faster since the db will quickly bottleneck.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
tsk2result=[]
for i in things:
    tsk1result=yield context.call_activity('task1', i) #start task1 and wait for result
    tsk2result.append(yield context.call_activity('task2', tsk1result)) #start task2 and wait for result
    if (not "tsk3result" in globals()) or (not stillrunning(tsk3result)): #test if tsk3result exists of if it's running
        tsk3result=context.call_activity('task3', tsk2result[0]) #if not already running, start it with most recent tsk2result
        tsk2result.pop(0) #remove that tsk2result 
        
while len(tsk2result)>0: #clean up any remaining tsk2result
    if (not stillrunning(tsk3result)): #same as above but it won't not exist by now
        tsk3result=context.call_activity('task3', tsk2result[0]) 
        tsk2result.pop(0) #These lines shouldn't repeat but it's just an abstract anyway
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
```

I don't actually need to do anything with `tsk3result`

Comment: You can use SubOrchestrator for Task2 and task3 callSubOrchestrator. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sub-orchestrations?tabs=python)

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT actually suborchestrator doesn't work because the first one waits for the sub to complete.  It has to start a new orchestrator which is what I ultimately did.